# Let $G$ be a simple graph with n vertices where every vertex has degree at least $n/2$. Prove that $G$ is connected.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Hi I need major help with these types of proving questions concerning connections and graphs. For this particular question I know you can prove using contradiction i.e when $G$ is not connected and there exists some vertices in $G$ with degree at most $n/2$. But I am not clear of the steps to take to prove that if there is such a vertice then the graph is still connected.

Help will be greatly appreciated!:))

Comment: In fact we have more stronger [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy.E2.80.93Chv.C3.A1tal_theorem). See Dirac's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Your on the right way. Assume that $G$ isn't connected, then it has at least 2 connected components. So by Pigeonhole Principle there exists a connected component, say $H$ with at most $\frac n2$ vertices. So now take $v \in V(H)$. Then by the assumption has a degree of at least $\frac n2$. But these edges are all in $H_1$, which is impossible as $H_1$ has at most $\frac n2$ vertices.